# Mineração de texto com Scikit-learn

Tags: python, aprendizagem-de-máquina, padrão-de-texto, machine-learning

Estou fazendo algumas pesquisas na área de análise de sentimentos, então estou fazendo alguns testes em um banco de dados de texto para obter resultados. Eu estava procurando por tutoriais entre outras formas de informação na internet e cheguei à conclusão de que é bem usado o biblioteca scikit  do python. No entanto, estou com dificuldade de colocar essa biblioteca para funcionar. Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda.

**Classe *Init***

```
import codecs
import baseline


def loadContent():
positiveData = codecs.open('opinioesNegativas.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8').readlines()

file = codecs.open('opinioesPositivas.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8')
negativeDate = file.readlines()

data_set = [0 for i in range(2000)]
label_set = [0 for i in range(2000)]

data_set[:1000] = positiveData
data_set[1000:] = negativeDate

for i in range(2000):
    if i < 1000:
        label_set[i] = "p"
    else:
        label_set[i] = "n"

return data_set, label_set


def run_baseline():
# getting the data#
data_set, label_set = loadContent()
baseline_classifier = baseline
# Pre-processing and setting the data to train and test model#

data_set = baseline_classifier.data_TFIDF_transform(data_set)
# data_set = baseline_classifier.data_transform(data_set)

folds = 10
scores = baseline_classifier.runKFoldCrossValitation(data_set, label_set, folds)

return scores

scores = run_baseline()

print(scores)
print("Baseline Accuracy: {} +/- {}".format(scores.mean(), scores.std() ** 2))

print(scores)
print("Stylometric Accuracy: {} +/- {}".format(scores.mean(), scores.std() ** 2))
```

**Classe Baseline**

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import StratifiedShuffleSplit, cross_val_score, train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsOneClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC

classifier = OneVsOneClassifier(SVC(kernel='linear', random_state=84, probability=True))


# training method #
def buildModel(train, labels):
# train_transformed = tf_idf.fit_transform(train)
classifier.fit(train, labels)


# predicted method #
def predict(test_data):
# test_transformed = tf_idf.fit_transform(test_data)
return classifier.predict(test_data)


# Pre-processing and setting the data to train and test model#
def data_transform(data_set):
transform = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 1))
data_set = transform.fit_transform(data_set)
return data_set


def data_TFIDF_transform(data_set):
tf_idf = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 1))
data_set = tf_idf.fit_transform(data_set)

return data_set


def runKFoldCrossValitation(data_set: object, label_set: object, folds: object) -> object:
classifier = OneVsOneClassifier(SVC(kernel='linear', random_state=84, probability=True))
# Split Data
train_data, test_data, train_label, test_label = train_test_split(data_set, label_set, test_size=0.1,
                                                                  random_state=0)

# Class Stratified 10-fold Cross Validation
skf = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=folds)

# Cross Validation
scores = cross_val_score(classifier, test_data, test_label, cv=skf)

return scores
```

**Erro apresentado**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Jeferson/PycharmProjects/NewProject/TestePython.py", line 40, in <module>
   scores = run_baseline()
File "C:/Users/Jeferson/PycharmProjects/NewProject/TestePython.py", line 36, in run_baseline
   scores = baseline_classifier.runKFoldCrossValitation(data_set, label_set, folds)
File "C:\Users\Jeferson\PycharmProjects\NewProject\baseline.py", line 42, in runKFoldCrossValitation
   skf = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=folds)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n_splits'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qual versão da scikit vc esta usando? No que voce chamou de classe baseline, logo inicio vc faz um import assim:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import StratifiedShuffleSplit
```

Mas se [consultar a documentação](http://lijiancheng0614.github.io/scikit-learn/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html), vai verificar que essa é uma classe da versão **0.17** e que não existe o parametro nominal `n_splits`.

```
sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedShuffleSplit(y, n_iter=10, test_size=0.1, 
train_size=None, random_state=None)
```

E se consultar o [changelog da versão **0.18.1**](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new.html) vai verificar a seguinte observação:

> All cross-validation utilities in sklearn.model_selection now permit one time cross-validation splitters for the cv parameter. Also non-deterministic cross-validation splitters (where multiple calls to split produce dissimilar splits) can be used as cv parameter. The sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV will cross-validate each parameter setting on the split produced by the first split call to the cross-validation splitter.

Ou seja talvez vc tenha que atualizar a lib e usar  [sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html), que é uma outra classe, que recebe outros parametros, inclusive `n_splits`.

```
sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=10, test_size=0.1, 
train_size=None, random_state=None)
```

Comment: Exatamente eu estava usando a versão 0.17 no qual estava no conda que e o conjunto que eu estava usando do python. Atualmente eu atualizei para 0.18.1 com python 3.5.

Comment: No entanto apresentou erro e deu está mensagem: DeprecationWarning: This module was deprecated in version 0.18 in favor of the model_selection module into which all the refactored classes and functions are moved. Also note that the interface of the new CV iterators are different from that of this module. This module will be removed in 0.20.
  "This module will be removed in 0.20.", DeprecationWarning)

Comment: De acordo com meu código como seria minha importação? os parâmetros tão passados corretos?

Comment: A msg diz exatamente o que eu te respondi, na verdade, pelo que vc apresenta aqui nem chega a ser uma msg de erro e sim um "warming", o que vc tem de fazer é usar a nova classe, como eu sugiro no ultimo parágrafo.

Comment: @Rivaldo Hater você conseguiu?

Comment: Sim, com algumas mudanças. @AndréNascimento

Comment: Excelente resposta. +1